# Adobe Photoshop: How to make texture for a mask?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I am trying to figure out how to make a part of an image have the same texture as a separate masked image. Here is what I have:

[image: Work in progress]

I'd like for the mountain to be more smooth and have the texture of this face without the mask being visible as it is now. Basically, I'd like the mountain behind this face to have a smooth texture of this face. How can I do that?

I have read and tried [this way of how to add texture to an image](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/textures.html), but it might be different due to the mountains being more rigid.

I'm currently using Photoshop Beta, but I could definitely switch to Photoshop 2023.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Maybe you expect something like the image above.

It's based on a sideways photo of a female. A selection was made along the head and neck edge and the background of the female photo was removed. The same selection is used to get a piece of mountains to a new layer above the original mountain terrain image layer.

The head clip is on the top, it's desaturated (no color from it) and its brightness is used to vary the brightness of the underlying mountain clip. Blending mode hard light is made for this.

To make the blending result of the head clip and the mountain clip to fit to the colors and geometry of the background terrain you must

- insert adjustment layers SEPARATELY for the head clip and the mountain clip. If you are lucky a curves adjustment layer only for the head clip is enough, but you may as well need another for the mountain clip and even a Hue/Saturation layer to adjust the tone of the mountain clip.
- wipe off smoothly the scrag side of the head and mountain clips. Even the ear should be faded because it's geometrically too obscure. This is done best with layer masks for easy fine tuning.

This result might have been at least a little impressive say 20 years ago. In recent years it has became sub-standard because 3D modelling and 3D texture mapping could create a terrain which contains a face sculpted of rock and snow. The version above is only a mix of 2D photos. People who make videogames, movies and flashy illustrations use 3D techniques. Even hobbyists can do it without investing to complex software. They can use Blender (freeware). But to do it one must to use an year or two to learn the skills.

Just now a clever enough question to an AI image generator web service might give it as well, but without using an year to learn Blender. Unfortunately I do not know the right question.

Comment: Are you suggesting something such as Maya? I may still have access to that, and that might be a better solution indeed! I just wanted to try out more of PS edit manipulation.

Comment: @leguchi Using properly advanced 3D software like Maya or Blender is out of my capabilities. I have only seen photorealistic results they can make in skillful hands. I am sure that with them it is possible to make a sculpted human figure or texturize an existing 3D model so that it's smooth enough to look a human figure, but still it's like like it's made of rock and snow like upper slopes and mountain tops in Himalaya. BTW I asked could you accept simply a whitened female side profile photo which is greyscale, only toned a little blueish like mountain tops?